# How many AT-AT walkers attacked Hoth?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, battle-of-hoth

I believe in the movie itself we are only able to see perhaps five onscreen at the same time, and I'm also pretty sure there is a point after two have been destroyed during the battle where we still see at least three together on screen.  So is five the best official number available?

Comment: Wookieepedia cites "at least 9" in a [couple](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Hoth) of [places](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Blizzard_Force). The citations are direct from Episode V but it would be difficult to keep track of all the AT-ATs in all the shots. And that would just be a lower bound anyway.

Comment: Hm, I wonder how that number is calculated, since there's definitely never a group shot with that many.

Comment: It's not a canon figure. They seem to be basing it on one of the games and the fact that there's a throwaway line in the film about "blizzard-9".

Comment: yeah i dont think you ever see more then 5 or 6 in a shot, and half the shots look like the same group (since they are the same props after all lol)

Comment: @JoeM Exactly. You'd have to somehow keep track of which AT-AT was which as you cut from one shot to the next. The best bet to get a count would be the novelization.

Comment: Here's the most I could find in a screenshot: http://images.wikia.com/fanon/images/7/73/AT-AT_walkers.jpg

Comment: It's best not to add answers to elderly questions when you find a new source. Instead you can either self answer or (as you've very graciously done below) mention it in a comment and hope that another user adds that source into their own answer.

Comment: It doesn't help for an answer, but one of the reasons for the small number on-screen was that the moving walkers required stop-motion animation, which was work intensive, and the models were expensive. That's the reason why, if you look closely, the further walkers don't actually move because they're cardboard cutouts.

Comment: Why didn't they attack from multiple directions? Or did they, off-screen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Twelve.

The (canon) *[Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy)* factbook states that Veers' attack force consisted of twelve walkers.

> With an orbital bombardment now impossible, General
> Maximilian Veers moved immediately to execute a ground
> assault: **he would land Blizzard Force’s dozen AT-ATs beyond
> the shield’s perimeter, march overland to the shield generator,
> and destroy it.**
>
> ...
>
> **Three walkers stumbled into a crevasse attempting a southerly traverse
> of the Kerane Valley, but Veers knew speed was critical and advanced
> across the Nev Ice Flow with his remaining nine, leaving the laggards
> to be extracted after the battle.**

This accords with the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_%28novel%29) which states that there were '*at least a dozen*' obsrved by a Rebel officer.

> Through the blizzard, the small dots seemed to be advancing at a slow
> yet steady pace, churning up clouds of snow as they moved toward the
> Rebel base.
>
> The officer raised his electrobinoculars and focused on the
> approaching objects. **There must have been a dozen of them resolutely
> advancing through the snow,** looking like creatures out of some
> uncharted past. But they were machines, each of them stalking like
> enormous ungulates on four jointed legs.

### Film

The single largest number seen on screen in ESB is the group of five making the direct assault on the base. As far as I can tell, two more walkers (one carrying the AT-AT commander) approach the shield generator from a different angle.

[image]

Taking into account the one destroyed by Luke's speeder, the one destroyed by Luke's grenade and a deleted scene in which one of the walkers was destroyed by blaster fire (see below) that means that there were at least five and possibly as many as seven in the battle.

[image]

### Databank

The [Star Wars Databank](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Databank), considered a canon source of information about the Star Wars universe, contains this still image of the Battle of Hoth with six walkers visible.

[image]

This [Galaxy of Adventures](https://twitter.com/starwars/status/1263529996934471680) short film shows *seven* walkers in loose formation. Six are immediately visible and one is hidden behind the second from the left and is seen shortly afterward.

[image]

Comment: @JoeM - I'm just rummaging through the "making of" DVD to see if there's a model shot.

Comment: If this tweet can be considered canon, we can say with certainty at least seven, as you can see that many briefly when the speeders make their initial attack run towards the AT-ATs. https://twitter.com/starwars/status/1263529996934471680

Comment: @JoeM - I count six on that attack run at 0:20

Comment: At 0:20 you can see six. But the second one from the left has another one directly behind it, which becomes visible in the next second. At 0:22 you can see it tiny and way in the back.

Comment: @JoeM - Ah yes, as the speeder goes under the walker you can see it become visible behind the second-from-left

Answer (score -1):

From The picture, it looks like there are six. I think that there are three though. In the fifth episode, when the general is looking through his macronoculars, he sees three walkers. I don't know where the other walkers came from though, but originally, there are three.

Comment: Do you have any reason for thinking there were three? Answers need to have some basis in facts.

Comment: @Bellatrix Just from looking at SonOfFett's post history, I'm 99.99999% certain he's trolling.  Either that or he's a 3 year old with a remarkably advanced writing ability.

Comment: Hey. I love Star Wars. Don't blame me for giving my response. geez. and I'm, not three.